# How to find large directories?

Tags: linux

I have a VPS on Linode,and its storage is almost full,so I want to find out the largest directories,when I type in

`du -hs * | sort -rh | head -30`

it shows below:

[top 30 large directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyy0F.png)
and this is the storage use:

[storage useage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vY9JS.png)
It seems the storage useage doesn't match the total storage,is there anyone can tell me why,thank you

Comment: `du / -h --max-depth=1`, this will give you the direct descendants  of /, then you can go deeper.

Comment: @Yaron Its total storage is also 65G,but I have a 95G SSD

Comment: I can't understand, this doesn't show you the total amount alone, it's a listing of root based dirs along with their sizes.

Comment: @Yaron I meanI have a 95G SSD for this VPS,but total size of root based dirs is 65G,why other 30G gone

Comment: in that case you'll find the additional 30GBs as files in /, unless they have been deleted but still in use (There's a way to find files like this using `lsof`.

Comment: @Yaron Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command for starters:

`sudo du -h -x --max-depth=1 / | sort -hr`

Where:

**du** - estimate file space usage

- -h - print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
- -x - skip directories on different file systems
- --max-depth - print the total for a directory (or file, with --all) only if it
            is   N   or  fewer  levels  below  the  command  line  argument;
            --max-depth=0 is the same as --summarize

**sort** - sort lines of text files

- -h - compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)
- -r - reverse the result of comparisons

And you will get the list of 1st level directories sorted by size in descending order. Next is to investigate based on the largest directories, what is eating all the space, using the same command above but replace the directory parameter from `/` to the path you want to explore.

Answer (score 0):

I use this command for the root folder `/` to check where the biggest directories are located, but you can use to any other directory of your choice

```bash
[sudo] du / -hxd 1 -t 1M | sort -hr
```

- `-h` from human-readable, print sizes in human readable format (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
- `-x` skip directories on different file systems
- `-d` from depth, print the total for a directory (or file, with --all) only if it is N or fewer levels below the command line argument
- `-t` from threshold, exclude entries smaller than SIZE if positive, or entries greater than SIZE if negative